# Passing props to deactivated component in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I've implemented the Tab feature using "keep-alive", like below, I want to pass "items2" data to the component when the selected currentTabComponent is 'Old', how do i make this work? is there any workaround?

```
<template>

   <div>
      <button @click="currentTabComponent = 'New'"> New </button>
      <button @click="currentTabComponent = 'Old'"> Old </button>
   </div>

  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="currentTabComponent" :items="currentTabComponent === 'New' ? items : items2"></component>
  </keep-alive>

</template>
```

In the logic, i have,

```
 <script>

  export default {
   data() {
     return {
        currentTabComponent: "New",
        items:['one','two','three'],
        items2:['five','six','seven']
       }
     }
  }
  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if you use `keep-alive` props will be passed in the usual way, dynamic or not. So if there is a change in props it should reflect in the subcomponent. `keep-alive` specifically helps in preserving state changes when the component is not used, and not resetting the state when the component is shown again. But in both cases, props will work fine.

Check the below code:

```
<div id='component-data'>
  <button
    v-for="tab in tabs"
    v-bind:key="tab"
    v-on:click="currentTab = tab">
    {{ tab }}
  </button>

  <keep-alive>
    <component v-bind:is="currentTab" 
      :items="currentTab == 'Bags' ? bags : shirts"
      class="tab"></component>
  </keep-alive>
</div>

<script>
  Vue.component('Bags', {
    props: ['items'],
    template: "<div>Showing {{ items.toString() }} items in bags.</div>"
  });
  Vue.component('Shirts', {
    props: ['items'],
    template: "<div>Showing {{ items.toString() }} items in shirts.</div>"
  });

  new Vue({
    el: "#component-data",
    data: {
      tabs: ['Bags', 'Shirts'],
      currentTab: 'Bags',
      bags: ['Bag one', 'Bag two'],
      shirts: ['Shirt one', 'Shirt two']
    }
  });
</script>
```

You should make sure that the sub-components 'New' and 'Old' have declared the `items` props in their component definition. Also I hope 'New' and 'Old' are the registered names of the components you are using for tabs.

Comment: my code and yours like very similar, can you tell why it worked in your case, please?

Comment: @Nag Yes sure I can check, can you share more information on the new and old components?

Comment: old and new components basically loop through the array(items) and displays, that's it.

Comment: Now I get it, you are not actually assigning a different data element, you are just changing the array element and that doesn't change the component!

Comment: @Nag That will not make any difference, you could just change the same code so that it passes different data attributes, and it still will work.

Comment: @Nag I have updated the code so that it passes different data attributes, it still works.